# Time ranges in Google Calendar's month view

Tags: google-calendar

I prefer to use Google Calendar's month view, but it currently only shows my events' start times and not when they end. This is very inconvenient when I'm trying to schedule multiple events for the day: I have to scope down to week/day view to see the ranges, and then back up to calendar view when I'm done.

Is there any way to show the event's start AND stop times in month view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, but agenda view will show you the coming month in a linear vertical view with start and end times for all events and allows you to expand or contract that view.

Comment: Too bad, but very glad you pointed out Agenda View to me! Thanks!

Comment: However the end time is not shown in Agenda view when you embed the calendar... very frustrating ... any solutions